# What is the meaning of the returend array of exec()

Tags: javascript, regex

For instance one has the simple regular expression:

```
var regex = /([^\\^\{^\}]+)|(\\[A-Za-z]+(\{[^}^{]*})*)|($[.]+$)|($$[.]+$$)/g;
```

and a string to check:

```
var text = '\\a{b}{c}{d}';
```

on witch the function `var matched = regex.exec(text)` is runned.
The returned Array `machted` looks now like:

```
matched =['\\a{b}{c}{d}', undefined, '\\a{b}{c}{d}', '{d}', undefined, undefined];
```

What do the single entries mean? And how to control them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It means what the documents say it means. Read them.

Comment: many of your escapes are not needed or missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var regex = /([^\\^\{^\}]+)|(\\[A-Za-z]+(\{[^}^{]*})*)|($[.]+$)|($$[.]+$$)/;
regex.exec('\\a{b}{c}{d}');
//=> ["\a{b}{c}{d}", undefined, "\a{b}{c}{d}", "{d}", undefined, undefined]
```

Resulting array contains matched groups where **first element of array is whole input that matched your regex**.

`undefined` means some of your groups didn't match anything and remained empty.

You can use **non-capturing groups and avoid undefined:

```
var regex = /(?:[^\\^\{^}]+)|(\\[A-Za-z]+(\{[^}^{]*})*)|(?:$[.]+$)|(?:$$[.]+$$)/;
regex.exec('\\a{b}{c}{d}');
//=> ["\a{b}{c}{d}", "\a{b}{c}{d}", "{d}"]
```

Comment: But why does it return `{d}` and not `{a}`?

Comment: Because you don't have `{a}` in your original string. How could it?

Comment: @Amadan Sorry I menat `{b}`

Comment: @Matthias: Tweak your regex to `var regex = /(?:[^\\{}]+)|(\\[A-Za-z]+(\{[^}{]*}))|(?:$$[.]+$$)/;` then you will get `["\a{b}", "\a{b}", "{b}"]`

Answer (score 1):

This is just how [RegExp.prototype.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) works.

The groups in your `regex` — contents inside the `()` chars — create elements in the returned array

Answer (score 1):

The zero-th element is the full match substring, the following elements are the substrings that were matched by capture groups `(....)`. For a simpler example:

`/(c)|(b(.))./.exec('abcdef')` should return `['bcd', undefined, 'bc', 'c']`. The pattern is an alternation between `(c)` and `(b(.)).`; `"bcd"` came before `"c"`, so the second alternative matched while the first didn't. Thus, first capture group `(c)` is `undefined`, since it matched nothing. The second capture group `(b(.))` matched `"bc"`. The third, `(.)`, matched `"c"`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a simplier example :

```
var text = 'azrt12345';
var regex = /([a-z]+)|([0-9]+)/;
var matched = regex.exec(text);
/* matched = ["azrt", "azrt", undefined] */
```

As you can see, the regexp catches an alpha string **or** a numeric one. As `text` begins with alpha characters, the first capturing group works, not the second. Then, `matched[0]` contains the whole string matched, `matched[1]` the first capturing group (with what it captured), `matched[2]` the second one (with nothing captured, then it contains `undefined`).

See this [excellent doc](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/regexp/exec) to understand the way it works.